# Why doesnt this motor activate? edit

Tags: motor

[image]

Its 3v motor and my source is about 5.14v.
[image]

Comment: Because the red wire isn't connected? How are we supposed to tell from that blurred photo with your fingers in the way?

Comment: It's not clear from this photo what your circuit is. Draw a schematic please.

Comment: A circuit diagram would help, otherwise the answer will be “it’s connected wrong” or the “motor is faulty”

Comment: Nice pajamas though

Comment: Are we doing this in alphabetical order or what :)

Comment: The motor is not faulty cause I've tried it on its own. I removed the button.

Comment: So probably your LED is eating too much voltage. Measure it. BTW, you are going to burn it, you know..

Comment: You cant wire an LED and motor in series like that. When the motor is stopped the LED gets the full voltage and will burn out. It will also drop enough volts while it does that for the motor to not start.

Comment: Eugene, I'm a starter so I don't know much, so a LED can consume that much voltage? if my source is about 5.14v?

Comment: Trevor, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wire an LED and motor in series like that.

When the motor is stopped the LED gets the full start current of the motor and the voltage dropped across the LED will be large. The LED will burn out quite quickly and it will also drop enough volts while it does that for the motor to not start.

If you want the LED on when the motor is on, wire it in parallel as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDHK1q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: While the battery wasn't shown, I'll guess that internal battery resistance saved the LED from burnout (in the original battery + LED + motor circuit).